Struggling to Connect Bitnami Keycloak 26.0.5 to External Infinispan
I’m fairly new to setting up Keycloak with external configurations and have been working for weeks to set up a simple demo connecting Bitnami Keycloak 26.0.5 to an external Infinispan instance. Unfortunately, I haven’t been successful yet.
I’ve gone through several tutorials, such as:

Keycloak Cluster using JDBC_PING for Distributed Caching
Keycloak Cluster Setup with Docker Compose and JDBC_PING
Keycloak Quarkus Distribution with Standalone Infinispan Setup

Unfortunately, many of these tutorials seem outdated, with deprecated configurations or missing steps for Keycloak 26. In each case, I encountered errors I couldn’t resolve.
While trying to set up the configuration, I’ve learned some of the terminology and gained a basic understanding of the infinispan.xml and cache-ispn.xml files, but I still can’t seem to get Keycloak to successfully connect to Infinispan.
Could anyone provide me with some guidance a starting point on how to connect Bitnami Keycloak 26.0.5 to an external Infinispan instance? Thank you!
This has been the base dockerized keycloak that I have been using to tinker with keycloak:
version: '3.8'
services:
postgresdb_18:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak_18_data
    ports:
      - "9878:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_26_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"  # Add this line to enable host resolution
  

  # keycloak
  keycloak-1-26:
    build:
      context: .  
      dockerfile: ./keycloak/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "9444:8443" # Https Only
    environment:
        # Keycloak Props
        
        - KC_FEATURES=token-exchange,ciba,admin-fine-grained-authz,client-policies,recovery-codes
        - KEYCLOAK_PRODUCTION=true # Defaults = false
        - KEYCLOAK_CREATE_ADMIN_USER=true
        - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
        - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
        - KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
        - KEYCLOAK_LOG_LEVEL=info # Default = info
        - KEYCLOAK_ROOT_LOG_LEVEL=INFO # Default = INFO
        - KEYCLOAK_ENABLE_HEALTH_ENDPOINTS=true
                
        # Database Props
        - KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_VENDOR=postgresql
        - KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_HOST=host.docker.internal
        - KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PORT=9878 
        - KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_NAME=keycloak_18_data
        - KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_USER=keycloak
        - KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
                
        # Host Security Props (HTTPS)
        - KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false # Default = false
        - KEYCLOAK_ENABLE_HTTPS=true
        

        
        ## If you want to use PEM for https instead of SSL
        - KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_USE_PEM=true # Default = false
        - KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE=/opt/keycloak/conf/truststores/server.crt.pem
        - KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE=/opt/keycloak/conf/truststores/server.key.pem
        
    depends_on:
       - postgresdb_18


volumes:
  postgres_26_data:

and this is the Dockerfile related to it:
FROM bitnami/keycloak:26.0.5

COPY ./keycloak/truststores/server.crt.pem /opt/keycloak/conf/truststores/server.crt.pem
COPY ./keycloak/truststores/server.key.pem /opt/keycloak/conf/truststores/server.key.pem

 
# Set custom provider environment variable
ENV CUSTOM_PROVIDER_JAR_URL="https://github.com/klausbetz/apple-identity-provider-keycloak/releases/download/1.13.0/apple-identity-provider-1.13.0.jar"

# Install custom provider
ADD --chown=keycloak:root $CUSTOM_PROVIDER_JAR_URL /opt/bitnami/keycloak/providers/apple-identity-provider-1.13.0.jar


May I ask why you need an external Infinispan? Connecting an external Infinispan is only supported in multi-site deployment on the cloud. See https://www.keycloak.org/high-availability/introduction

@pruivo Well, the idea was that I would have an external infinispan which is decoupled from keycloak and can be managed separately, this documentation:
keycloak.org/server/caching
has given me the impression that it can done in the way that I have my implementation currently: , but it seems like there is no way, except by using this HA multi-site thingy, and now that you brought up HA, there are plans, in the future, that additional keycloaks might be added to my implementation seems like I have to go that route.

The most common use case for an external Infinispan is to store the sessions but, Keycloak 26 stores the sessions in the database. An external Infinispan is not required anymore. There are plans to support an external Infinispan to store session: see https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/33658

@pruivo Thanks for the info, since sessions are stored to database by default via the persistent-user-session feature, I think there is no need to complicate stuff with an external infinispan.
